# Coding and viewing output in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I find this interesting https://camo.githubusercontent.com/567f685fa08e065a58f4ac105dc033d0416444ec/68747470733a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f6a4f574434766b2e676966 and I want to try this so that I have an idea on how the query will be looked like when I coded it using SQLKata, the problem is I don't know how to start. I read something on Debugging Visual Studio code (From given link looked like I think it's on visual studio code) but it doesn't help. Does anyone have an idea that can lead me on the right track. Your help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Use LinqPad to Convert LINQ to SQL. It's a free tool can be downloaded [here](https://www.linqpad.net/). Here is an example [image: LINQPad]

Comment: I know LinqPad, but what I want is an output window for SQLKata.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to see the output in **DotNet Core** is to send the output to the **Console**, Where you executed the `dotnet run` command.

I believe that the example mentioned is built like this.

[image: Dotnet Application Console Demo]

To send compiled queries in SqlKata check the official docs
https://sqlkata.com/docs/execution/logging